# SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute() or dbSendStatement() instead of dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery()

Tags: sql, r, warnings, dbi

I would like to create a new database, which returns the results of a query as a dataframe. If I use `dbExecute()` or `dbSendStatement()`, as indicated in the warning message, it won't return the required dataframe. What can I do to remove this warning? Why am I getting these warnings?

```
drv <- RSQLite::dbDriver("SQLite")
con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, dbname= tempfile())
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, paste("CREATE TABLE activity",
        "(aid INTEGER, cid INTEGER,",
        "activity INTEGER, score REAL)"))
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
# Warning message:
# In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
#  SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute() or dbSendStatement() instead of dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery().
```

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: this warning is normal : a table creation query returns no data

Comment: If you want it to return the (clearly empty) table, then `dbExecute(con, "...")` (create the table), then `dbGetQuery(con, "select * from activity")` or `dbReadTable(con, "activity")`, both should return a 0-row `data.frame` with your desired columns/classes.